# Trouble accessing xaml resources from Community Toolkit in VSIX Extension

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, themes, vsix

I am writing a VSIX extension and am quite far down the line. I have created a XAML Window which displays XAML UI but I want it to match the current theme. I found the following article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix/recipes/use-themes?view=vs-2022 which which explains how to do this, and makes perfect sense. However, I get the following error: 'IOException: Cannot locate resource 'themes/themeresources.xaml'' I know that this error is telling me that the resources from the specific file is not loaded but I have no idea where to get this from.

I have been wiring XAML in WPF for about 10 years and know it very well.